# Add Cloud firestore library to chrome extension, content_scripts

Tags: google-chrome, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to add cloud firestore library to content_scripts?
I need to add firebase-app.js and firebase-firestore.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work, I just had to download the files from:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-bower
then I had to convert firebase-firestore.js to utc8
also added this to my manifest.json:`"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",`

Comment: Just a hint - you can accept your own answer as accepted answer. To show you have successfully solved your problem :) That way other users have it easier to see, that this question has a solution

Comment: What are you referring to when converting it to `utc8` ?