# Include firestore library in manifest.json

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore

So i've been working on a google chrome extension which alters HTML in a list of specific pages. What this means is that I don't have an HTML file to insert the firebase and firestore library urls into, which should then go into the manifest.json file.

After having downloaded the actual library files and added them to the content_scripts the firestore library seems to be throwing a error which tells me the firestore library file is not UTF-8 encoded. The firebase library itself works perfectly fine but the firestore file won't.

I've tried working around this issue by loading the libraries inside of my background.html and somehow parsing the data I get there to my actual app but this seemed very unpractical. There is also not a lot to be found when specifically looking for a combination between firestore and google chrome extentions.

UTF-8 Encoding the firestore file with the standard mac-os tools didn't do much for me either, as is suggested by one other issue I found on this matter.

So my question pretty much sums up to: "How do you include the firestore library into a google chrome extension through the manifest.json?".

- Haven't found any solution yet, one month later.

Comment: I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087962/5995040) would help, the OP downloaded the firebase-firestore.js and convert it to utc8 format. hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried these steps and they have not fixed my issue, I also think the OP in that post meant to write UTF-8 instead of utc8. Thanks for trying to help nonetheless!